# Print and echo causing my code not to work

Tags: php

My `echo` and `print` functions when used breaks my code. What is weird is that the `print` I use to return the data works just fine but when I use it in any other place it breaks. I have a PHP file in which a html file calls it but when I add `echo` or `print` to my PHP file it breaks and not sure why. My logs also aren't showing anything which is weird so I am unable to debug anything. What are the general reasons why `echo` and `print` will break code? I know `print` is similar to a return statement but why would `echo` not work.

My code is here:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$database;user=$user;password=$password";
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn);
    echo "Hi";
    \\Some more code here which is unnecessary to show because it makes a db call and returns the data just fine
    $dataOrders = json_encode($data);
    print $dataOrders;\\Here it works fine and returns the data just fine but when I add an extra print anywhere else or echo it breaks.
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: **Breaks Code** Can you try a more specific description of what Actually happens and maybe any error messages associated with the **break**

Comment: I assume you are replying to an AJAX call, is that right? And if it is, is the code that **breaks** in fact the Javascript code processing the reply?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess; you expect the data back as JSON and it cannot be parsed because you also echoed `Hi` which renders the JSON that follows it invalid (because AJAX will receive *all of the output*, not just the one from `print`).

Comment: @El_Vanja Welcome to the Limb :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ah yes, the magic of edited comments showing only after you post your own strikes again.

Comment: @El_Vanja always fun seeing you and Riggs on here. I have a haunch you are right I'll post the answer below to make it clear

Comment: @El_Vanja Not what I ment, Its nice to have some company :)# Way out here in the ether :)

Comment: Printing objects works best with a 3D printer instead of in PHP. PHP prefers strings or stringable types. Also you should prefer echo over print, because echo is a language construct and print is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be used for an AJAX call where it can only accept JSON as a return. You can validate this by looking at the Developer Console in the Network tab as well to see what is being returned. I've also added a JSON array that will have an error be added so your AJAX request can validate there's no error present.

```php
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn);
    \\Some more code here which is unnecessary to show because it makes a db call and returns the data just fine
    echo json_encode($data);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 1, 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}
```

This is also assuming that there's no code further below the try/catch which sends anything out to the page which would make the JSON invalid.

Comment: So in this case how will I be able to add echo statements? I use echo to debug my code. I just want to see values of some variables that are used by echoing them. I come from the Java world so is there anything like `System.out.println` that I can use without having AJAX receiving all the output?

Comment: You could go directly to the URL, or you could use something like POSTMAN to mimic the requests. That's how you would debug for an AJAX call

Comment: But what if you have complicated logic in the code that formats a SQL statement to something complicated and you want to see how that SQL statement looks before it makes the AJAX call. POSTMAN will not be able to help in that case or the developer tools.

Comment: Are you asking how to setup logging in PHP? That's what it feels like here where you want the code to execute but specific messages you want to see as it runs. You could look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php but there's better distributed ways of doing this

Comment: Oh okay i see ty!

Comment: @Robin yep the solution is log your debug output to a file instead of echoing it